# Media Gallery MySql Database Design

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I am putting together a database which will hold information on various media items of different media types. Each media item could then be added to a media collection which could then be used to create media sliders, galleries etc.

Here is an example db

```
media_types
-----------
id    code    title
1     images  Images
2     videos  Videos
3     files   Files

gallery_items
-------------
id    gallery_id    mediaTypeId    mediaId
1     1             1              2
2     1             3              1
3     1             2              3

images
------
id title        filename
1  X-Wing       xwing.png
2  Tie Fighter  tie.png
3  A-Wing       awing.jpg

videos
------
id title        filename
1  Hoth         iceplanet.wmv
2  Bespin       bespin.ogg
3  Tatooine     desert.mpeg

files
-----
id title                       filename
1  Death Star Plans            bothanx.pdf
2  Millenium Falcon Schematics yt1300.pdf
3  Rebel Alliance              manifesto.doc
```

I would like to be able to select all items in a particular gallery with one MySql statement but at present, I can only work out how to perform it in two steps:

1) Select all items from the gallery_items table with a particular gallery id

2) Select the item details from the relevant media type table by analysing the mediaTypeId

In the example I give, the media type tables are very simple, sharing the same columns but in reality they will have different amounts of columns and different column names. A basic join statement on mediaId won't work as each media type table could share the same id.

I had thought about using a unique mediaId across all media types but this would enforce an absolute relationship between the gallery_items table and the media types tables which I would like to avoid (not all items in the media types tables will end up in a media collection). Perhaps the solution would be to create another table, media_items, which created a unique media id for each each which would then be used in each media type table? I am however weary of unnecessary table proliferation.

Any suggestions on how to best approach this design would be most appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

IIWM: I would have one table of 'media types' like you have it. Then another table of media with a unique ID, media type, filename, etc. Last have a table with gallery info - unique id, media id and any other gallery info.

To make it more useful you could have a table of 'changes' that track datetime of assignments to/from a gallery for each piece of media, date it was received, sold, etc. This would track the 'lifespan' of each piece in your collection.